# autocorrelation definition

Tags: probability, statistics, signal-processing, correlation

There is something that is not clear for me in the definition of an autocorrelation and how to calculate it physically. Namely, following a definition for a random process with real values $x(t)$:
$$ R(t_1,t_2) = E [x(t_1)\cdot x(t_2) ]$$
So we calculate the expected value of the product of the values at time $t_1$ and $t_2$. The question is however how to calculate this value? I mean that from a process we have only two values $x(t_1)$ and $x(t_2)$ and there is no statistics in order to average this values. Or does this mean that we perform thought experiment and restart a process from the beginning and in this case we will get another values $x(t_1)$ and $x(t_2)$ in accordance to the distribution of the random process x?

Comment: $x(t)$ is a random variable for each t e.g. it might represent a dc voltage which has a fixed average value in time but which is inherently noisy, possibly described by the addition of normal random variable with mean 0

Comment: I mean how the autocorrelation is calculated when the x(t) is random variable

Comment: Is $x(t_1)$ a measure of a variable, or a set of measurements?

Comment: You might model a voltage as $x(t)=sin(t)+B$ where B is a normal random variable of mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ say. So each $x(t)$ is a random variable. Then the autocorrelation as you have defined it is $x(t_1)x(t_2)+\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the pragmatic comment. I am however interested in the definition. What I was talking about is ergodic process of the order 2 (I found it in the literature).  I mean that if there is no special considerations on the expected value and auto correlation (ergodic property gives that), there is no statistical values possible since the process could not be repeated. Thus $E [x(t_1)\cdot x(t_2) ]$ could not be measured statistically